# Finding intermediate colours between two xyY colour points

Tags: color-spaces

I am working in an application where I need to know the intermediate points between two xy coordinates in CIE 1931 colour space.

In the picture below we can see that a linear transition (straight line) between A and B will go through a series of other colours, and I am struggling to find a mathematical way of describing the transitions between A and B in order to get intermediate points.

Any ideas?

[image: CIE 1931 colour space - image from wikipedia]

Comment: I fail to see a problem here: What else would you expect the intermediate color between red and blue to be?

Comment: One thing is what you see, another is what you can tell a  software. What I am looking for is a way of computing the intermediate points "between" any two colours.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought you were complaining that a linear transition would not be a good solution.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I fail to see how this is a *design* question. Seems more of a *math* question to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question, not a design one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This anwer is just intended to give you some ideas.

The Cie lab, (actually any color space) is a 3d space.

I'm not sure on what is the "real" 3d space, becouse for practical reasons it can be converted into ortogonal coordinates, so you have 3 coordinates, not 2.

"Linear transitions" are relative to what road you take. To make transitions between colours you can take several aproaches.

[image: Types of transitions]

This will give you diferent "Middle colours". In an HSB for example, the model 2 will mantain the Bright and saturation on the same level just rotating the Hue value. In terms of Hue it is a linear transition. But if you use another aproach the B and S values will be splited into 2 paths, like model 3, and that will not be linear.

On example No. 3 however, you don't cross diferent hue values, just the Origin and Target hue values.

---

Of course "linear transition"s is the obvius choice if you are using a mathematical aproach.

You can use some "S" curves or probably a logartimic curves, but, On what basis you choose each one? Probably you want a perceptual model?

[image: Types of transitions]

---

At the end, a simple ((X2-X1)/2)+X1 will give you the middle value in X axis. The same for the y axis.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is the [weighted arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean) between the two colour coordinates:

First of all, what do you have?

- You have the *x* and *y* values for A; let’s call them *x*<sub>A</sub> and *y*<sub>A</sub>.
- You have the *x* and *y* values for B; let’s call them *x*<sub>B</sub> and *y*<sub>B</sub>.

Now to describe an intermediate value, you need a parameter, which I will call *t.* This parameter shall range between 0 and 1 and it shall be such that (for example):

- For *t* =0, you get colour A.
- For *t* =1, you get colour B.
- For *t* =½, you are exactly in the middle between A and B on your line. Or with other words: You get a mix of colours A and B that contains equal parts of both.
- For *t* = ¼, you get a colour that is mostly A with a bit of B. More precisely, it’s three parts A, and one part B.
- For *t*= ¾, you get a colour that’s three parts B and one part A.

To sum it up, *t* shall be such that it gives the relative amount of B in your mixed colour – you get the relative amount of A from this automatically: It’s 1−*t*. *t* is our weight for B in the weighted mean; 1−*t* is our weight for A. Now, how do you calculate *x(t)* and *y(t)* for a given *t*:

- *x(t)* = (1−*t*)·*x*<sub>A</sub> + *t·x*<sub>B</sub>
- *y(t)* = (1−*t*)·*y*<sub>A</sub> + *t·y*<sub>B</sub>

If you let *t* smoothly go from 0 to 1, your colour transitions smoothly from A to B along the line in your diagram.

Comment: won't this only work if the transitions in colour space are linear?

Comment: How do you define a *linear colour space?* At the end of the day, it probably all depends on what you consider the best mix between two colours, which is probably something you could excessively debate about. Anyway, I understood your question such that you want colours from the line you depicted.

Comment: I think this aproach is correct, just remember that in any colour model you have 3 coordinates, not 2.

Comment: @Rafael: Well, the colour space the OP was asking about isn’t as it misses saturation. You might notice the lack of anything blackish in the diagram.